# Join few column into one table

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I join this into one table?

```
select xxx.* from
(
(select a from x where a in (q)) as kk,
(select a from x where a in (w)) as hh,
(select a from x where a in (e)) as gg
) xxx
```

I want to get:

```
gg|hh|kk
---------
1 |2 |3
```

(the result is only an example)

Comment: Your question is entirely unclear.  The reformatting is trivial.  I might suggest that you *delete* this question and ask another question that is clearer.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff I edited question. I hope that this is clearly now

Comment: . . I really did mean that you should delete the question and ask another.  By changing the question you invalidate answers.  That attracts downvotes and is rude.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking to do is called a pivot. Here's a simple example with your data:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT xxx.* from
    (
    (select 1 as val, 'a' AS id) UNION ALL
    (select 2 as val, 'b' AS id) UNION ALL
    (select 3 as val, 'c' AS id)
    ) AS xxx
)
SELECT *
FROM cte AS p
PIVOT (MAX(val) FOR id IN ([a], [b], [c])) AS pvt
```

Comment: It looks fine, but I can't use it. I have few subqueries. And I have always the same error :"Incorrect syntax near ','"  It shows me error on point before 'a' , 'b', 'c'

Answer (score 0):

OK, what you didn't mention was that the query you posted doesn't work (you have extra brackets). Below is the answer that I think you want:

From your first example...

```
select * 
from
(select 1 as a) as table1,
(select 2 as b) as table2,
(select 3 as c) as table3;
```

if you have multiple columns:

```
select table1.aa as a, table2.bb as b, table3.cc as c
from
(select 1 as aa, 11 as aaa) as table1,
(select 2 as bb, 22 as bbb) as table2,
(select 3 as cc, 33 as ccc) as table3;
```

Both give:

```
a   b   c
1   2   3
```

Answer (score -1):

How about this?

```
select xxx.*
from (select 1 as a, 2 as b, 3 as c) as xxx;
```

Comment: this is just a reformatted version of what they provided in the question...

Comment: @Gordon Linoff I have to use subqueries. So I can't use your query

Comment: @Mao . . . I think my point is that you need to better explain the question.  There are a bunch of trivial answers, and your question isn't clear.  And, I should note that this answer does use subqueries.